# SharePoint 2007 - How to create a site template programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, sitetemplate

In my SharePoint 2007 project I have to use 3 site templates. Using these templates I create new sites programmatically. I also want to **create the templates programmatically**.

1. Is that possible?
   If yes, I guess I have to use a SPSite object for creation.
2. What should I do exactly?

Comment: I posted an answer but I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SPWeb.SaveAsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.saveastemplate.aspx) method to save a SharePoint site as a site template solution in the Site Template Gallery.